# Drill down when a single cell is clicked on a cross table

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I currently have a cross table that I have built that contains quite a few aggregations (using custom expressions) broken down by names on the vertical.  Upon clicking on a cell I would like to show the details behind that data point.   However, when clicking in the cross table it automatically selects the entire row and this shows all of the details behind that row, which is not what I want.  Is there any way to setup a cross table so that you can click on a single cell (sort of like you'd have the ability to do in Excel)?  The only solution I can think of would be to build multiple cross tables with single calculations, so that when clicked it will show the detail data behind that single value.

Thanks so much for the help and possible solutions!

Comment: Short answer, no, it's not possible to select a single cell. That cell in the cross table is found by analyzing many rows of a table and because Spotfire is row oriented, the entire record must be selected, not just a column of the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom expressions with an if statement - sum(if([name]='a',1,null)) write one for each name on your vertical then remove the vertical break down leaving only the expressions that have each category already split. this way you can select a single cell value. this method does require a lot more expression in your cross table.

Comment: Can you explain a it more about it or show some demo?